# Как обновлять текст в Label`е с определенной частотой?

Tags: c#

Как обновлять текст в Label`е с определенной частотой(1 сек. например)?.пробовал такой код:

```
     for (; ; )
        {
            Task.Delay(1000);
            countDownLabel.Content =
                String.Format(/*подстановка обновляемого текста*/);
        }
```

,но окно виснет.Как решить проблему?

Comment: Почему бы не использовать таймер (`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Threading.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Виснет, потому что вы не ожидаете таск: метод `Task.Delay` возвращает управление сразу и вы т.о. сильно нагружаете UI перерисовкой. Правильнее так:

```
for (; ; )
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    countDownLabel.Content = String.Format(/*подстановка обновляемого текста*/);
}
```

Возможно, что вам захочется уметь останавливать обновление:

```
private async Task UpdateLabel(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        countDownLabel.Content = String.Format(/*подстановка обновляемого текста*/);
    }
}

private void Do()
{
    // обновляем лейбл в течение 10 секунд
    var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    UpdateLabel(tokenSource.Token);
}
```

---

Если с async/await вы не очень знакомы, можете использовать [таймер](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Не забудьте про [Control.Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) для доступа к элементам интерфейса.

```
timer = new Timer(UpdateLabel, null, 1000, 1000);
...
private void UpdateLabel()
{
    if (countDownLabel.InvokeRequired)
    {
        countDownLabel.Invoke(UpdateLabel);
    }
    else
    {
        countDownLabel.Content = String.Format(/*подстановка обновляемого текста*/);
    }
}
...
timer.Dispose();
```