# Как запустить циклическую(вечную) функцию на C# в новом потоке?

Tags: c#, многопоточность, async-await

Есть подключение к серверу по Websocket

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/client_websocket")
{ 
    ws.OnOpen += (sender, e) => this.Connected();
    ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
    ws.OnError += (sender, e) =>//делаем что-то при ошибке
    ws.OnClose += (sender, e) => //делаем что-то при отключении
    ws.Connect();
    while (true)
    {
    }
}
```

Я его запускаю и т.к. метод крутится в `while` , то дальше ничего не идёт в потоке.
Мне нужно запустить функцию подключения в новом потоке. Что-то не пойму, как работать с `Thread` и `Async-awayt`.
Подскажите, как такое реализовать?

Comment: А чего вы хотите добиться? Зачем вам вызывать функцию подключения в новом потоке?

Comment: @andreycha Я запускаю подключение, а потом выполняю другие операции. В данном случает поток висит на подключении. До других операций дело не доходит. Например я хочу, что б пользователь ввёл параметры и они отослались в поток Connection

Comment: А зачем вам `while (true)`?

Comment: @andreycha Ах- да. работает. Спасибо. Ну а вообще тогда другой вопрос- как быть, если в потоке бесконечная функция- например- каждую секунду- таймер?

Comment: Не понял, поясните.

Comment: @andreycha while убрал.всё гуд. Я просто про то, что б запускать несколько функций в потоках и каждая выводила каждую секунду,скажем, время- либо писала, одна - X, другая-Y. Я где-то видел примеры и не могу найти. И тогда в чём разница между Threads и Async awayt. Как я понял Async на самом деле не асинхронный- он просто прерывает поток как-то...вообщем немного запутался в асинхронности((

Comment: Используйте для этого таймер. [Вот тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/472639/106) немного было про повторяющиеся задачи. Про отличия async/await [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/491783/106).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как обновлять текст в Label\`е с определенной частотой?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/472632/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-label%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b9)

Answer (score 1):

1. Если вы хотите запустить цикл в новом потоке:

   ```
   new Thread(() =>
   {
       while (true)
       {
           //TODO
       }
   });
   ```
2. Если вы хотите запустить цикл асинхронно используя пул потоков:

   ```
   Task.Run(() =>
   {
       while (true)
       {
           //TODO
       }
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал обернуть Ваш код в метод и вызвать его так:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyMethod());
```

Так же есть перегруженные версии с передачей CancellationToken.
В даном примере await async не нужны

Comment: От числа одновременно подключенных клиентов зависит. Более 100 клиентов => решения на потоках умирают.

Comment: Ваш вариант решения?

Comment: Зависит от того что внутри цикла.

Comment: Ну а минусовать то решение зачем. Если все равно не знаем, что будет внутри цикла?....

Comment: Потому что я придерживаюсь точки зрения что не следует поощрять ответы на плохие вопросы. Не переживайте, на этом сайте полно ботов-плюсовальщиков.

Comment: Я как-то себе представлял, что

Comment: Я как-то себе представлял, что минусовать плохие ответы. А на плохие вопросы просто давать объяснение

Comment: Обсуждения организации сайта ведутся на Мете, а не в комментариях к случайному ответу.